# haraka smtp server : Error: unable to get issuer certificate

Tags: email, ssl, tls1.2, haraka

Getting haraka email server error when attempting to use as outgoing only :

[tls] secured: cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 version=TLSv1/SSLv3 verified=false error="Error: unable to get issuer certificate"

... entire server log for this send email attempt

```
[NOTICE] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] connect ip=111.222.333.444 port=55152 local_ip=:: local_port=587
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] running connect_init hooks
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] running connect_init_respond
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] running lookup_rdns hooks
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] running connect hooks
[PROTOCOL] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] S: 220 mydomain.com ESMTP Haraka 2.8.8 ready
[PROTOCOL] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] C: EHLO mydomain.com state=1
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] running ehlo hooks
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] running capabilities hooks
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] running capabilities hook in tls plugin
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] hook=capabilities plugin=tls function=tls_capabilities params="" retval=CONT msg=""
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] running capabilities hook in auth/flat_file plugin
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [auth/flat_file] Auth disabled for insecure public connection
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] hook=capabilities plugin=auth/flat_file function=hook_capabilities params="" retval=CONT msg=""
[PROTOCOL] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] S: 250-mydomain.com Hello mydomain.com [111.222.333.444], Haraka is at your service.
[PROTOCOL] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] S: 250-PIPELINING
[PROTOCOL] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] S: 250-8BITMIME
[PROTOCOL] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] S: 250-SIZE 0
[PROTOCOL] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] S: 250 STARTTLS
[PROTOCOL] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] C: STARTTLS state=1
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] running unrecognized_command hooks
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] running unrecognized_command hook in tls plugin
[PROTOCOL] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] S: 220 Go ahead.
[DEBUG] [-] [core] Upgrading to TLS
[DEBUG] [-] [core] TLS secured.
[INFO] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [tls] secured: cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 version=TLSv1/SSLv3 verified=false error="Error: unable to get issuer certificate"
[INFO] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] hook=unrecognized_command plugin=tls function=tls_unrecognized_command params="STARTTLS" retval=OK msg=""
[INFO] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] client [111.222.333.444] dropped connection
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] running disconnect hooks
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] running disconnect hook in tls plugin
[DEBUG] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] hook=disconnect plugin=tls function=hook_disconnect params="" retval=CONT msg=""
[NOTICE] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [core] disconnect ip=111.222.333.444 rdns="mydomain.com" helo="" relay=N early=N esmtp=Y tls=Y pipe=N errors=0 txns=0 rcpts=0/0/0 msgs=0/0/0 bytes=0 lr="" time=0.06
```

here is entire nodejs client code to send outgoing email

```
// https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer

var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport('smtp://myloginid:mypassword@mydomain.com:587');

var mailOptions = {
    host: 'mydomain.com',
    port: 587,
    from: 'myloginid@mydomain.com', // sender address
    to: 'mygmailname@gmail.com', // list of receivers
    subject: 'Hello',
    text: 'Hello world',
    debug: true,
    auth: {
        user: 'myloginid',
        pass: 'mypassword'
    }
};

// send mail with defined transport object
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if(error){
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: ' + info.response);
});
```

node --version
v6.6.0

I am using TLS certs generated from tutorial at

https://letsecure.me/secure-web-deployment-with-lets-encrypt-and-nginx/

here are the four cert files

cert.pem  chain.pem  fullchain.pem  privkey.pem

I used two of these TLS cert files for haraka

```
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/${FRESH_DOMAIN}/privkey.pem ${HARAKA_HOME}/config/tls_key.pem
cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/${FRESH_DOMAIN}/cert.pem    ${HARAKA_HOME}/config/tls_cert.pem
```

Here are the errors

client nodemailer

```
Error: unable to verify the first certificate   at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:416:38) code: 'UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE' }
```

haraka log error :

```
[INFO] [06F7A5F3-E976-404E-8629-CAB3771964E9] [tls] secured: cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 version=TLSv1/SSLv3 verified=false error="Error: unable to get issuer certificate"
```

Any suggestions ?

PS. Strangely it currently does work OK if I use swaks to send emails even though above nodejs email client fails

```
swaks -f myloginid@mydomain.com -t mygmailname@gmail.com -s localhost -p 587 -au myloginid -ap mypassword
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The choice of letsencrypt TLS cert files I used above works for other email servers like postfix ... yet haraka instead wants file fullchain.pem

wrong one previously used :     cert.pem

correct TLS cert  :  fullchain.pem

This file change fixed the TLS error so Haraka now sends outgoing email OK with above nodejs client code